Scipy root equation solving
I have a problem when solving a system of equations. To understand the code,
the term: (1. - Ni_oct + delta_Ni_mod)  used to be a variable. But I have to implement it in order to remove one equation that is not seen here. This equation is what is seen in the variable Q. Q should equal to iterable j from the loop. The goal is to find for which delta_Ni_mod the diff satisfies the tolerance. But for some reason the code goes not find any solutions and is infinitely running. Increasing the tolerance is not an option, as then I get solutions that logically not satisfy a suitable difference. Btw I should have mentionen that values from the iterable j are very small numbers like between 10^-170 and 10^-21
Would be grateful if someone helps out. What I tried so far is below
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root


dH_3 = 5.02*1.602e-19
N_A=6.022e23
R = 8.314 
T_values = np.arange(0,1300, 50)
dH_5_neutr = 0.708*1.602e-19
p_H2 = np.logspace(-6,1, num=100)
dH_6_neutr = 6.151*1.602e-19

p_H2 = np.logspace(-6,1, num=100)
K_def3 = np.exp(-(dH_3*N_A)/(R*T_values))
Kp_def3=K_def3
K_def5_neutr = np.exp(-(dH_5_neutr*N_A)/(R*T_values))
Kp_def5_neutr=K_def5_neutr
K_def6_neutr = np.exp((205.15/2)/R)*np.exp(-(dH_6_neutr*N_A)/(R*T_values))
Kp_def6_neutr = [[K_def6_neutr[i] * (p_H2[j]/10e-5) for j in range(len(p_H2))] for i in range(len(K_def6_neutr))]



# Initialize variables
delta_Ni_mod_max = np.float64(-0.002)
delta_Ni_mod_min = np.float64(0.0)
tolerance = 1e-20
diff_list = []
delta_Ni_mod_values = []
resultlist_def1_3_4_5_6 = []
Q_list = []
delta_Ni_mod = (delta_Ni_mod_min + delta_Ni_mod_max) / 2
for j, l, Kp_def6_subarray in zip(Kp_def3, Kp_def5_neutr, Kp_def6_neutr):
    for m in Kp_def6_subarray:
        def equations(vars):
            Ni_oct, V_oct, O_o, V_o, Al_tet, Al_oct, V_tet = vars

            eq1 = Ni_oct + V_oct + (0.999 - Ni_oct + delta_Ni_mod) + Al_oct - 2.0  # Oktaederplätze
            eq2 = O_o + V_o - 4.0  # Sauerstoffplätze
            eq3 = -1 * Ni_oct - 3 * V_oct + 2 * V_o + Al_tet - 2 * V_tet  # Ladungsbilanz
            eq7 = Al_tet + V_tet - 1  # Tetraederplätze
            eq8 = Al_tet + Al_oct - 2.0  # Massebilanz Al
            eq10 = (Al_oct * V_tet) / (V_oct * Al_tet) - l  # Kp_def5_neutr Site exchange
            eq11 = ((V_o * (Ni_oct ** 2)) / (O_o * ((0.999 - Ni_oct + delta_Ni_mod) ** 2))) - m  # K Bildung Sauerstoffvakanzen

            return [eq1, eq2, eq3, eq7, eq8, eq10, eq11]

        initial_guess = [0.999,  # Ni_oct # 0.999
                         0.0001,  # V_oct
                         3.999,  # O_o
                         0.0001,  # V_o
                         1.,  # Al_tet
                         1.,  # Al_oct
                         0.001]  # V_tet
        #delta_Ni_mod = (delta_Ni_mod_min + delta_Ni_mod_max) / 2

        while True:
            
            sol = root(equations, initial_guess, method='lm', tol=1e-40)
            Ni_oct, V_oct, O_o, V_o, Al_tet, Al_oct, V_tet = sol.x

            Q = (V_oct * (0.999 - Ni_oct + delta_Ni_mod) ** 2) / (Ni_oct ** 3)
            diff = j - Q

            if abs(diff) <= tolerance:
                diff_list.append(diff)
                delta_Ni_mod_values.append(delta_Ni_mod)
                resultlist_def1_3_4_5_6.append(sol.x)
                Q_list.append(Q)
                break

            if diff > 0:
                # Q muss positiver gemacht werden, also delta_Ni muss richtung negative Zahl gebtacht werden

                delta_Ni_mod_min = delta_Ni_mod
            else:
                # Hier gilt K < Q, also muss Q negativer gemacht werden
                # Q muss negativer gemacht werden, also delta_Ni Ri 0 gebracht werden
                delta_Ni_mod_max = delta_Ni_mod

            delta_Ni_mod = (delta_Ni_mod_min + delta_Ni_mod_max) / 2```


I'm not really sure what is going on here. Where are your numbers coming from? Do you know a root exists? Do you have a minimal reproducible example? Also, note that your j values are much smaller than standard machine precision (64-bit floating point machine precision is around 1e-15), so those j values are, for all intents and purposes, 0.

With these input values this should work out. These are equlibrium constants. dH_3 = 5.021.602e-19,
N_A=6.022e23,
R = 8.314 ,
T_values = np.arange(0,1300, 50),
dH_5_neutr = 0.7081.602e-19,
p_H2 = np.logspace(-6,1, num=100),
dH_6_neutr = 6.151*1.602e-19,
K_def3 = np.exp(-(dH_3N_A)/(RT_values)),
K_def5_neutr = np.exp(-(dH_5_neutrN_A)/(RT_values)),
K_def6_neutr = np.exp((205.15/2)/R)np.exp(-(dH_6_neutrN_A)/(R*T_values)),
Kp_def6_neutr = [[K_def6_neutr[i] * (p_H2[j]/10e-5) for j in range(len(p_H2))] for i in range(len(K_def6_neutr))],' The roots exist

@Reinderien, thanks for the hint. Did not know that I could edit the code.

@Reinderien, the adjusted one will work. By your comment "The beginning of the while loop attempts to access a bunch of variables that are out of scope.", what would be the impact of that and how does the change then needed to be?

All fixed up, thanks.

So you said that this runs infinitely, but it doesn't - it terminates pretty quickly.

@Reinderien the code runs. The actual problem about a not suitable difference still occurs. Q is extremely dependent on the tolerance. The purpose is to find the root of Kp_def3 depending on delta_Ni_mod so that I get same values for Q as they are supposed to be in Kp_def3. Any ideas where my approach is not fine?

Rewrite the first section of your program to look like
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

from scipy.constants import (
    e,    # atomic unit of charge (in C)
    N_A,  # Avogadro constant
    R,    # molar gas constant
)

delta_Ni_mod_max = -0.002
delta_Ni_mod_min = 0


def equations(
    vars: np.ndarray, j: float, l: float, m: float,
) -> tuple[float, ...]:
    Ni_oct, V_oct, O_o, V_o, Al_tet, Al_oct, V_tet, delta_Ni_mod = vars

    # Oktaederplätze / octahedral sites
    #    + Ni_oct              - Ni_oct
    eq1 =        + V_oct + .999        + delta_Ni_mod + Al_oct - 2

    # Sauerstoffplätze / oxygen sites
    eq2 = O_o + V_o - 4

    # Ladungsbilanz / charge balance
    eq3 = -Ni_oct - 3*V_oct + 2*V_o + Al_tet - 2*V_tet

    # Tetraederplätze / tetrahedral sites
    eq7 = Al_tet + V_tet - 1

    # Massebilanz Al / mass balance, aluminium
    eq8 = Al_tet + Al_oct - 2

    # # Kp_def5_neutr Site exchange
    eq10 = Al_oct * V_tet/(V_oct * Al_tet) - l

    # K Bildung Sauerstoffvakanzen / formation oxygen vacancies
    eq11 = V_o*Ni_oct**2/(O_o * (1 - Ni_oct + delta_Ni_mod)**2) - m

    Q = (V_oct * (0.999 - Ni_oct + delta_Ni_mod)**2)/Ni_oct**3
    eq_j = j - Q

    return (eq1, eq2, eq3, eq7, eq8, eq10, eq11, eq_j)


def main() -> None:
    # tolerance = 1e-21

    diff_list = []
    delta_Ni_mod_values = []
    resultlist_def1_3_4_5_6 = []

    dH_3 = 5.02*e
    dH_5_neutr = 0.708*e
    dH_6_neutr = 6.151*e

    T_values = np.arange(0, 1300, 50)
    N_A_RT = N_A/(R * T_values)

    # p_H2 = np.logspace(-6, 1, num=100)
    # K_def3 = np.exp(-dH_3 * N_A_RT)
    # Kp_def3 = K_def3
    # K_def5_neutr = np.exp(-dH_5_neutr * N_A_RT)
    # Kp_def5_neutr = K_def5_neutr
    # K_def6_neutr = np.exp(205.15/2/R) * np.exp(-dH_6_neutr * N_A_RT)
    # Kp_def6_neutr = np.outer(K_def6_neutr, p_H2/10e-5)

    p_H2_log = np.linspace(-6, 1, 100) * np.log(10)
    K_def3_log = -dH_3 * N_A_RT
    Kp_def3_log = K_def3_log
    K_def5_neutr_log = -dH_5_neutr * N_A_RT
    Kp_def5_neutr_log = K_def5_neutr_log
    K_def6_neutr_log = 205.15/2/R - dH_6_neutr*N_A_RT
    Kp_def6_neutr_log = np.add.outer(K_def6_neutr_log, p_H2_log + 4*np.log(10))

    # Rewrite this to use the log quantities
    for j, l, Kp_def6_subarray in zip(Kp_def3, Kp_def5_neutr, Kp_def6_neutr):
        for m in Kp_def6_subarray:
            initial_guess = (
                0.999,   # Ni_oct
                0.0001,  # V_oct
                3.99,    # O_o
                0.0001,  # V_o
                1,       # Al_tet
                1,       # Al_oct
                0.001,   # V_tet
                (delta_Ni_mod_min + delta_Ni_mod_max)/2,
            )

Remove your inner loop and convert that to an additional equation on Q. Also, convert the entire program to use the logarithmic scale; otherwise you are guaranteed to have stability and accuracy issues.
